# reformatting strings with included variables

Tags: python, variables, robotframework

I have a library full of variables(that I do not wish to hand edit), it looks like this:

```
def get_variables(gateway):
    variables={
        'gateway':gateway, 
        'license_test_data':gateway['license_data'],
        'license_for_application':gateway['license_for_application'],
        'Valid_Login_Test_Vairables':{'valid_ssh_command':['ssh '+gateway['DeviceUnderTestUserid']+'@'+gateway['DeviceUnderTestIP'],'password:']}
        #around 3000 more just like this or worse
       }
return variables
```

I need to import this information into a python data structure *without replacing the 'gateway' variables*.  In other words I want to be able to:

```
print vars['Valid_Login_Test_Vairables']['valid_ssh_command']
```

and get exactly this

```
'ssh +gateway['DeviceUnderTestUserid']+'@'+gateway['DeviceUnderTestIP'],'password:']
```

Instead I end up with this:

```
print vars['Valid_Login_Test_Vairables']['valid_ssh_command']

"ssh gateway['DeviceUnderTestUserid']@gateway['DeviceUnderTestIP']", 'password:'
```

What I have been trying is this:

```
import varfile
import dummy.gateway
vars=varfile.get_variables(dummy.gateway)
```

with my dummy.gateway looking like this:

```
gateway['license_test_data'] = "gateway['license_test_data']"
gateway['license_for_application'] = "gateway['license_for_application']"
gateway['license_for_setup'] = "gateway['license_for_setup']"
```

What can I do to get the exact contents of my variable file into a useful data structure?

Comment: Both what you have and what you want contains a syntax error. But aside from that, you should start thinking about XML or JSON to serialize your data.

Comment: Could you fix your quoting?  It's a bit confusing, so I'm not quite understanding your problem.

Comment: Your first example isn't even valid Python. Please post something that actually works, to start with.

Comment: larsman, the weird layout is a robot framework requirement, I can't change to XML or JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question somewhat difficult to understand, but if I manged to do so correctly, the following produces what you said you wanted from what you have.

```
# used as a stand-in for your 'import dummy.gateway'
dummy_gateway = {}
dummy_gateway['license_test_data'] = "gateway['license_test_data']"
dummy_gateway['license_for_application'] = "gateway['license_for_application']"
dummy_gateway['license_for_setup'] = "gateway['license_for_setup']"
dummy_gateway['DeviceUnderTestUserid'] = "gateway['DeviceUnderTestUserid']"
dummy_gateway['DeviceUnderTestIP'] = "gateway['DeviceUnderTestIP']"

# your example code corrected and reformatted to be slightly more readable
def get_variables(gateway):
    variables={
        'gateway':gateway,
        'license_test_data':gateway['license_test_data'],
        'license_for_application':gateway['license_for_application'],
        'Valid_Login_Test_Vairables':{
            'valid_ssh_command':
                ['ssh '+gateway['DeviceUnderTestUserid']+'@'+
                    gateway['DeviceUnderTestIP'],
                 'password:']
            }
        #around 3000 more just like this or worse
       }
    return variables

vars = get_variables(dummy_gateway)
print vars['Valid_Login_Test_Vairables']['valid_ssh_command']
```

The result, which is a `list` composed of two strings:

```
["ssh gateway['DeviceUnderTestUserid']@gateway['DeviceUnderTestIP']",'password:']
```

Hope this helps.

P.S.  BTW the name `vars` conflicts with the name of a [built-in Python function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=vars#vars) in the Standard Library, so using it for the name of one of your variables is generally considered a bad programming practice even when doing so works, as in this case as far as it goes.

Comment: vars is not the real variable that I use, I made it generic for the question.   But I guess I wasn't clear in the question, but the point of this exercise is to avoid hand recoding the variables file.  I need to read it into python data structures so that I can reformat it.

Comment: @Skip Huffman: Sorry I misunderstood. If you could show, or at least describe the format of the data in this variables file, and perhaps what kind of data structure you'd like to put it into (or ask what's the best one for some particular purpose), then maybe you'll get better help.

Comment: Certainly.  The data structure of the file consists of a single module called variables.  This module describes a python dictionary, each element of the dictionary might be a string, list or another dictionary.  Each of these elements might be fully defined in this file, or might include a variable that is passed to the variable file at import time in the "gateway" dictionary.
I wish to import this variables dictionary intact, with the variables unreplaced. I can then combine this data with some information from a couple other sources and write out again as a newer, better variables file.